# How to iterate over multiple files by name within given range?

Tags: python-3.x, glob

So I'm trying to iterate over multiple xml files from a library which contains more then 100k files, I need to list files by their 3 last digits.
Expected result is a list of files named from 'asset-PD471090' to 'asset-PD471110' or 'asset-GT888185' to 'asset-GT888209', and so on.

My Code -

'''

```
import glob

strtid = input('From ID: ') # First file in range
seps = strtid[-3:]
endid = input('To ID: ') # Last file in range
eeps = endid[-3:] 
FileId = strtid[:5] # always same File Id for whole range

for name in glob.iglob('asset-' + FileId + [seps-eeps] + '.xml', recursive=True):
    print(name) # iterate over every file in given range and print file names.
```

'''
The error I'm getting is

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'

How to load a specific range of input files ?

Comment: `r = range(int(seps),int(eeps)+1)` and use each part of `r` in some `with open(f'asset-{FileId}{part_of_r}.xml') as f:`?

Comment: Your question is unclear, your code does not reproduce your problem, your error messages are missing (choose 1, dont do all in 1 question) - etc. Pleas read [ask] and provide a [mre]

Comment: Thank you Patrick for your quick response, sorry for not being clear, I'm new to Stack and coding, trying my very best.
I've edited my question, hope it's better now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the error tells you: you try to use `-` on strings:

> ```
> strtid = input('From ID: ') # string
> seps = strtid[-3:]          # part of a string
>
> endid = input('To ID: ')    # string 
> eeps = endid[-3:]           # part of a string
>
> FileId = strtid[:5]         # also part of a string 
>
> # [seps-eeps]: trying to substract a string from a string:    
> for name in glob.iglob('asset-' + FileId + [seps-eeps] + '.xml', recursive=True):
> ```

You can convert the string to a integer using `int("1234")` - won't help you much though, because then you only have *one* (wrong) number for your iglob.

If you wanted to give them as glob-pattern you would need to encase them in stringdelimiters - and glob does not work that way with numberranges:

- `"[123-678]"` would be *one digit* of 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8 - not 123 up to 678

However, you can test your files yourself:

```
import os

def get_files(directory, prefix, postfix, numbers):
    lp = len(prefix)       # your assets-GT
    li = len(postfix) + 4  # your id + ".xml"
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(directory):
        for file in sorted(files): # sorted to get files in order, might not need it
            if int(file[lp:len(file)-li]) in numbers:
                yield os.path.join(root,file)

d = "test"
prefix = "asset-GT"  # input("Basename: ")
postfix = "185"      # input("Id: ")

# create demo files to search into
os.makedirs(d)
for i in range(50,100):
    with open (os.path.join(d,f"{prefix}{i:03}{postfix}.xml"),"w") as f:
        f.write("")

# search params        
fromto = "75 92"     # input("From To (space seperated numbers): ")

fr, to = map(int,fromto.strip().split()) 
to += 1 # range upper limit is exclusive, so need to add 1 to include it

all_searched = list(get_files("./test", prefix, postfix, range(fr,to)))
print(*all_searched, sep="\n")
```

Output:

```
./test/asset-GT075185.xml
./test/asset-GT076185.xml
./test/asset-GT077185.xml
./test/asset-GT078185.xml
./test/asset-GT079185.xml
./test/asset-GT080185.xml
./test/asset-GT081185.xml
./test/asset-GT082185.xml
./test/asset-GT083185.xml
./test/asset-GT084185.xml
./test/asset-GT085185.xml
./test/asset-GT086185.xml
./test/asset-GT087185.xml
./test/asset-GT088185.xml
./test/asset-GT089185.xml
./test/asset-GT090185.xml
./test/asset-GT091185.xml
./test/asset-GT092185.xml
```